# Using recursion properly

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I am a beginner at dealing with recursion in C++. A problem asks us to find the maximum element of an array.

The author's solution was the following:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr_max(int arr[], int len)

{
    if (len == 1)
        return arr[0];

    int sub_result = arr_max(arr, len - 1);
    return max(sub_result, arr[len - 1]);
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 8, 2, 10, 3 };

    cout << arr_max(arr, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

and my solution was the following:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int func(int arr[] ,int s) {
static int max = 0 ;
static int i = 0 ;
if(s == 0)
    return max ;

if(arr[i] > max)
    max = arr[i] ;
i++ ;
func(arr,s-1) ;
}

int main() {
int arr[6] = {11,5,48,100,45,67} ;
cout << func(arr,6) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Both codes are working but my questions are:

1. Am I using recursion properly and verifying the concept of recursion or I am doing something else? And
2. Is one code above better than the other one? Why?

Comment: Does your code (second snippet) works for negative numbers?

Comment: Using `static` or globals in recursion is valid, but defeating the idea, and therefore I consider it "cheating". Recursive functions should be "pure".

Comment: See what happens when you call your function multiple times.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, the `static` variables make this function not thread-safe; only one thread can be in this function at any one time or they will all step on each other's state.

Comment: FYI, as a beginner, I recommend always using braces after `if, for, while` and `do-while`.  This will eliminate a lot of defects and headache because indentation has no meaning to the C++ compiler.

Comment: the first difference is: the author of the original solution has formatted his code correctly. You did not. You need start from there. Your code cannot be read. Put some effort in your question if you expect any help

Comment: Do not tag C for questions involving only C++.

Comment: In most cases, using recursion properly means not using it. It's a powerful tool for **analyzing** algorithms, not so powerful for **implementing** them.

Comment: The problem with those `static` variables is deeper than the current comments point out. You can't call that function a second time, because `max` and `i` will have the leftover values from the first call, not the right initial values.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile your code, I get the error "main.cpp:14:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]".

I think the design of the provided answer is better because it doesn't run the risk of failing to return a value, the way yours does.

Think about what you need to know to make a recursive function work.

1.) What is the base case? What is the simplest version of the problem that you can answer right away? In this case, that happens if you have an array with just one element, which is by definition the biggest one in the array. (Note: You need to have error handling for empty arrays, too.)

So in the simplest case, you just return the only element in the array.

The recursive case requires you to think about what happens if you increase the size of the array. The way the provided answer does this is by recursively calling itself until the original single array of length `len` is split into `len` arrays of length 1. Then it comes back up the call stack by repeatedly returning the bigger of the last element in the array and the function called on the rest of the elements, excluding the last.

This means you're making `len` calls to `arr_max` and `len` comparisons. (If the array were really big, you might run out of memory doing it this way.)

Your function takes a base case where the array length is 0. But if the array has no elements, then it doesn't have a greatest element. Instead, you return 0. So this is a little weird. It's also a little weird the way you increment `i` from 0 but recursively call the function on `len-1`.

I think maybe you could benefit from rethinking the design in terms of base cases and recursive cases, and I think the advice to avoid using statics is probably a good one for this purpose.